# Group datatables

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I am using the datatable plugin :

I need to group row on the data on column 2 , I am using the the below code ,
HTML :

```
<table class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-sm mytable  ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ __('code') }}</th>
            <th >{{ __('value1') }}</th>
            <th >{{ __('description') }}</th>
            <th >{{ __('quantity') }}</th>
            <th >{{ __('amount') }}</th>
            <th >{{ __('total') }}</th>
            <th ></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="provider_cpts_div"> 
        <tr>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>xx</td>
            <td>www</td>
            <td>ww</td>
            <td>ww</td>
            <td>ww</td>
            <td>ww</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>xx</td>
            <td>www</td>
            <td>ww</td>
            <td>ww</td>
            <td>ww</td>
            <td>ww</td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script :

```
var collapsedGroups = {};

        var CptTable = $('.mytable').DataTable({

            rowGroup: {
            // Uses the 'row group' plugin
            dataSrc: 1,
         startRender: function(rows, group) {
        var collapsed = !!collapsedGroups[group];

        rows.nodes().each(function(r) {
          r.style.display = 'none';
          if (collapsed) {
            r.style.display = '';
          }
        });

        // Add category name to the <tr>. NOTE: Hardcoded colspan
        return $('<tr/>')
          .append('<td >' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
          .attr('data-name', group)
          .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
      }
    }
        });

        $('.mytable  tbody').on('click', 'tr.group-start', function() {
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            collapsedGroups[name] = !collapsedGroups[name];
            CptTable.draw(false);
         });
```

It is not working , it seems I missed something
this based on the sample :
https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/ua4yLscx/

I am not sure what I missed

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "_it is not working_"? It seems to be working OK as far as I can tell.

Comment: You probably should add `order: [ [1, 'asc'] ],` to the DataTable, so the initial sorting matches the grouping. And you probably have a typo in the style name `table-stripped` (should that be "striped" instead of "stripped"?). But apart from that, what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the missing was the'row group' plugin ,

I added the .js and .css

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.2/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.2/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this has fix my problem ...